# How to center multiple images using Bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap and trying to make 3 images to be centered. For example, red color boxes are how my images look like, and I want to make it look like blue color boxes:
[image]

I tried getting rid of the margin and padding, but I still want some space between the images. Also I tried using `{ display: table; }, display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle;` but somehow it does not do anything to my images... Is there a way to get images to the center with some padding to them in Bootstrap?  Below is my code:

```css
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

.row {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.column {
    flex: 33.33%;
    padding: 50px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="album text-center">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="column">
                <img src="images/tour1.jpeg" alt="one" style="width:100%">
            </div>
            <div class="column">
                <img src="images/tour2.jpg" alt="two" style="width:100%">
            </div>
            <div class="column">
                <img src="images/tour3.jpeg" alt="three" style="width:100%">
            </div>
            <div class="column">
                <img src="images/tour1.jpeg" alt="one" style="width:100%">
            </div>
            <div class="column">
                <img src="images/tour2.jpg" alt="two" style="width:100%">
            </div>
            <div class="column">
                <img src="images/tour3.jpeg" alt="three" style="width:100%">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Thank you!

Comment: are you sure you are using  / loading the bootstrap CSS library link ? they are centered already to me.

Comment: Do they look like the blue boxes in the picture? On my screen, they are only centered like the red boxes in the picture.

Comment: I tried but it only gives 1 x 1... I want to have exactly 3 images, centered towards the middle of the screen.

Comment: centered you mean => horizontally and vertically (middle of the screen
)?

Comment: Just horizontally! ```|   O O O   |``` like this, instead of ```|  O  O  O  |``` .

Comment: so you do want the images to be responsive and move when the page is smaller - means no matter what you want three images centered ?

Comment: Yes, so for now, when I minimize the window, the image gets smaller and stays 3 images in a row. But I just want to make sure they are aligned centered vertically...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223119/discussion-between-always-helping-and-sarah-kim).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Bootstrap 4** has `justify-content-around` class which does the job. Consider to use narrower container If you want to obtain smaller gap between images.

PS: You should avoid using `col` class within image wrappers.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row justify-content-around">
    <div class="colx"><img src="https://place-hold.it/200x400" alt="" class="img-fluid"></div>
    <div class="colx"><img src="https://place-hold.it/200x400" alt="" class="img-fluid"></div>
    <div class="colx"><img src="https://place-hold.it/200x400" alt="" class="img-fluid"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wtqzscg6/)

Comment: Is there a way to adjust the gaps between the images? I tried, and it stills looks like they are all in equal-sized gaps...

Answer (score 1):

Just add this class "justify-content-around".

```
    <div class="album">
        <div class="row justify-content-around">
            <div class="column">
                <img src="images/tour1.jpeg" alt="one" style="width:100%">
            </div>
            <div class="column">
                <img src="images/tour2.jpg" alt="two" style="width:100%">
            </div>
            <div class="column">
                <img src="images/tour3.jpeg" alt="three" style="width:100%">
            </div>
            <div class="column">
                <img src="images/tour1.jpeg" alt="one" style="width:100%">
            </div>
            <div class="column">
                <img src="images/tour2.jpg" alt="two" style="width:100%">
            </div>
            <div class="column">
                <img src="images/tour3.jpeg" alt="three" style="width:100%">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```